# Send array from Julia to Rust (using "ccall")

Tags: arrays, rust, julia, send

Can someone explain? How to send any array from julia to rust using "`ccall`" function. There is no problem with sending usial variables or constants.

I have `Julia` code:

```
A = Array{Float64,1}(undef, 2)
print("A is ",A, "\n")
ccall((:recvstruct, "target/debug/liblib"),Float64, (Ref{Array{Float64,1}}, Int32,), A, sizeof(A))
```

And `Rust`code

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn recvstruct(vec: &mut Vec<f64> , len: usize){
    println!("reiceved?: {:?}", len);
    println!("reiceved?: {:?}", vec);
}
```

Output is:

```
A is [0.0, 0.0]
Hello from cargo

reiceved?: 16
```

and weird endless array:

```
, 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000069329110091509, 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000693291559949425, 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000693291100915405, 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000693291559949425, 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000693291100915405, 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000693291559949425, 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000693291100915563, 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000693291559949425, 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000693291100915563, 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000693291559949425, 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000693291100915563, 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000693291559949425, 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000069329110091572, 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Julia installed: `Version 1.5.2`
Rust (cargo): `cargo 1.49.0 (d00d64df9 2020-12-05)`

Comment: I don't know much about Julia, but you shouldn't be using a `Vec` with ffi. Try using a `*mut f64` and see where that gets you. Also, make sure the endianness matches up between the two languages.

Comment: @Aiden4, I tried use *mut f64 in rust. Now I get ref on array but not values of the array`reiceved?: 0x7f0de6114670`

Comment: You can convert the pointer to a slice with the `slice::from_raw_parts_mut` function.  Remember that the `len` argument is the number of elements, not the number of bytes. Alternatively, you can use `ptr.read` to get the values you want. Beware, don't accidentally read uninitialized memory or use the array after it has been freed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Julia side

In `(argtype1, ...)` of `ccall` declare the type of first argument of `recvstruct` as a pointer to a memory address with [`Ptr{T}`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Core.Ptr).

direclty from ccall [`docs`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#ccall):

> Each argvalue to the ccall will be converted to the corresponding argtype, by automatic insertion of calls to unsafe_convert(argtype, cconvert(argtype, argvalue))

Pass the number of array elements and not the size in bytes of the array:

```
a = [2.0, 3.0]
result = ccall((:recvstruct, "target/debug/liblib"), Float64, (Ptr{Float64}, UInt,), a, length(a))
println("got: $result")
```

#### Rust side

Declare the first argument of `recvstruct` as a memory pointer to an array of `float64`.

Moreover use [`slice::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html) for getting the slice of values.

For example:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn recvstruct(array_ptr: *const f64, len: usize) -> f64 {
    _recvstruct(unsafe {
        std::slice::from_raw_parts(array_ptr as *const f64, len)
    }, len)
}

fn _recvstruct(vec: &[f64] , len: usize) -> f64 {
    match len {
        2 => vec[0] * vec[1],
        _ => 0.0
    }
}
```

Note that `from_raw_parts` is marked as unsafe. The Safety section of the manual page contains all the details to be considered.

Comment: is there a way to pass a pointer to an already modified array in Rust to julia? i tried passing a pointer using vec.as_ptr(). In rust it looks like `0x22402d0`, and in julia `Ptr {Float64} @ 0x00000000022402d0` after `unsafe_wrap (Array, output, n, own = false)` (output is a pointer from Rust), but I get an array of zeros, not a modified array in rust.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Look if and how long memory remain allocated where pointer is transferred to Julia. It is hard to say what may be wrong, Should help `std::mem::forget` on the rust vec?

Comment: Yes, you were right. But I used `let mut vec_send = ManuallyDrop :: new (vec);` So in this case `vec` is memorable for rust. May be helpfull for someone.